# Bayesian Network Meta-Analysis (gemtc) - Specifying the order of comparisons

Tags: r, bayesian

I'm working on a Bayesian Network Meta-Analysis using the gemtc package on a dataset similar to the following:

```
df <- data.frame(study = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D", "D", "E", "E", "F", "F", 
                           "G", "G", "H", "H", "I", "I", "J", "J", "K", "K"),
                                 treatment = c("A", "B", "B", "C", "B", "C", "A", "B", "B", 
                                                "C", "B", "C", "A", "B", "B", "C", "B", "C", 
                                                "A", "C", "B", "C"),
                                 responders = c(1, 5, 0, 0, 3, 1, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0,
                                                0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 9, 1, 1),
                                 sampleSize = c(32, 33, 30, 30, 18, 20, 15, 15, 20,
                                                20, 30, 30, 36, 32, 15, 15, 23, 22, 24, 23, 18, 16))
```

While I have been able to set up the network model and run the analysis just fine, I have been struggling with specifying the order in which I would like the treatments to be compared in the node-splitting consistency analysis. For example, I want the odds ratios and 95% credible intervals to be calculated using the "B" treatment as the reference group when comparing "B" with "A" and "C" as the reference group when comparing "A" with "C" and "B" with "C". Below is the code I have tried:

```
library(gemtc)
library(rjags)

# Create mtc.network element to be used in modeling ------
network <- mtc.network(data.ab = df)

# Compile model ------
network.mod <- mtc.model(network, 
               linearModel = "random", # random effects model
               n.chain = 4) # 4 Markov chains

# Assess network consistency using nodesplit method ------
nodesplit <- mtc.nodesplit(network.mod, 
                linearModel = "random", # random effects model
                n.adapt = 5000, # burn-in iterations
                n.iter = 100000, # actual simulation iterations
                thin = 10) # extract values of every 10th iteration
summary(nodesplit) # High p-values indicate consistent results

plot(summary(nodesplit))
```

My results provide ORs (95% CrIs) for:

- "A" vs. "C"
- "B" vs. "C"
- **"B" vs. "A"**

I have created a separate data frame specifying that I want "A" vs. "B" comparisons via:

```
# Specify desired comparisons ------
comparisons = data.frame(t1 = "A", t2 = "B")

# Assess network consistency using nodesplit method, adding comparisons argument ------
nodesplit <- mtc.nodesplit(network.mod, 
                comparisons = comparisons,
                linearModel = "random", # random effects model
                n.adapt = 5000, # burn-in iterations
                n.iter = 100000, # actual simulation iterations
                thin = 10) # extract values of every 10th iteration
summary(nodesplit) # High p-values indicate consistent results
```

But I still get "B" vs. "A" results. I have also tried specify t1="B", t2="A", and I get the same results. Any assistance with this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot reproduce the `network.mod <- ...` line: 
```Error in order(comparisons[["t1"]], comparisons[["t2"]]) : 
  argument 1 is not a vector ```
However, I do believe that it might have something to do with factor levels. Have you tried manually setting the treatment variable as factor and use different factor levels?

Comment: Ack, sorry about that. To answer your question, yes, I have converted the variable to a factor and assigned levels to no avail. I even uploaded my data to the online gemtc tool (https://gemtc.drugis.org/), and got the same results. I just wanted to avoid having to manually invert the values of the ORs.